# qt signals/slots in a plugin

Tags: c++, qt, boost, signals-slots

I have an app with such structure: all the datatypes (`class INode`) are stored in plugins (DLLs). Some of the datatypes can be drawn (if they're `IDrawable`).

To load an object of, e.g. `class PointCloudNode: public INode` I have a special input plugin (DLL) which is called `class PointCloudParser: public IIOPlugin` and `IIOPlugin` is a thread with some specific functionality: `class IIOPlugin: public QThread`.

All the objects are created by `NodeFactory` class which is a singleton stored in separate DLL.

And here's the problem:

```
void PointCloudNode::update()
{
QObject::connect (this,SIGNAL(tmptmp()),this,SLOT(drawObject()));
emit tmptmp();
}
```

If I do this from any thread (main thread or the Input Plugin thread)

```
NodeFactory* fab = NodeFactory::getInstance();
boost::shared_ptr<INode> pc(fab->createNode("pointCloud","myPC"));
boost::shared_ptr<IDrawable> dr = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<IDrawable>(pc);
dr->update();
```

The update launches, the `tmptmp()` signal is emitted, and the slot (`drawObject()`) executes correctly.

**BUT**
if do just the same, but create the object in my Input Plugin, pass over the shared pointer and execute `dr->update()` in another function, the slot `drawObject()` is never entered though all the code is executed (including `connect`, etc.).

To be more precise, here's the Input Plugin:

```
 void PointCloudParserPlugin::doLoad(const QString& inputName, boost::shared_ptr<INode> container)
 {
   NodeFactory* factory = NodeFactory::getInstance();
   boost::shared_ptr<INode> node = factory->createNode("pointCloud", inputName);

   // here goes the loading itself, nothing special...

   container->addChild(node); //that's the container where I keep all the objects

   //boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<IDrawable>(container->getChild(inputName))->update();
   //If I uncomment this line, it all works: the slot is launched.  
   emit loadingFinished(inputName); // it executes the following function
 }
```

The last emit is connected to this:

```
 void GeomBox::updateVisualization(const QString& fileName)
 {
   boost::shared_ptr<INode> node = container_->getChild(fileName);
   boost::shared_ptr<IDrawable> nodeDrawable = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<IDrawable>(node);
   nodeDrawable->update(); //this is the problem line: update() executes, connect() works, but the slot never runs :(
 }
```

How come? The `node` object is the same all the way through, it is valid. Every line in code in launched, `QObject::connect` doesn't write anything to debug window, the signal `tmptmp()` is emitted, but the slot `drawObject()` in one case is never reached? Any ideas?

**Upd.:** If I do not inherit `IIOPlugin` from `QThread`, everything works fine (i.e. load the object in the main thread). I expected the signals/slots to work across the threads...

Comment: have you done, qmake, make clean, make all again?

Comment: * have you included this last line in the source for plugins? ( Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(xxx,XXX))

Comment: yep, I've done all of that
it seems something's wrong with signal/slots between DLLs..

Comment: Did you double check if plugin is loaded? Put some asserts on plugin loading code

Comment: Yes, all the plugins are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending a signal across to a different thread, you might need to explicitly tell Qt that the connection should be a queued one:

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(tmptmp()), this, SLOT(drawObject()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
```

By default Qt will use `Qt::AutoConnection` as that last parameter, and it will choose whether to use a direct connection (if the slot is in the same thread as the emitter) or a queued connection (if the slot is in a different thread). But since your thread is in a separate library, maybe Qt isn't making the right assumption here.